# Ruled lines in input field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make one `input` field with a notebook style of ruled entry. How can this be done.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: Ruled input area]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of CSS3 `repeating-linear-gradient`, which is just like a regular `linear-gradient` but makes unending repeats easy.

Use this to generate a gradient background on a `textarea` with hard one-pixel color-stop for the color of rule that you want it to have.

Example:

```css
label, textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px; line-height: 27px;
  padding: 0px 5px; margin: 8px; 
}
label { font-weight: bold; }
textarea {
  border: none; outline: none;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom, transparent, transparent 26px, #33d 27px
  );
  background-attachment: local;
}
```

```html
<label>General Business Information</label><br/><br/>
<textarea rows="8" cols="50">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</textarea>
```

In the example above..

`repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 26px, #33d 27px)`

..makes the gradient go from top to bottom, uses a transparent color as the starting point, and then ends with transparent at 26 pixels. It then uses a blue color at the 27px as a hard color-stop. This `27px` is made equal to the `line-height` used for the `textarea` so as to neatly align the text inside the rules.

`background-attachment: local;` - makes the background scroll along with content if the `textarea` gets scrollbars.

Removing `border` and `outline`, finishes it looking like a notebook ruled sheet.